# SQLAlchemy - Complex Sub-querying with join

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, graphene-python

I need to be able to convert this to SQLALchemy, I'm a bit new but it is required. The SQL Query is this:

```
SELECT name, 
(
    SELECT value from account_settings 
    WHERE name = "max_allowed_records" and accounts.id = account_settings.account_id
) AS max_allowed_records,
(
    SELECT count(*) from employees 
join employeelists on employees.employeelist_id = employeelists.id 
where employeelists.account_id = accounts.id 
group by employeelists.account_id
) AS RECORD_COUNT FROM accounts
having coalesce(max_allowed_records,0) < coalesce(RECORD_COUNT,0);
```

In Joined form, I think they produce the same result (tried it like this to better visualize it in SQLAlchemy Query):

```
SELECT accounts.name, account_settings.value AS max_allowed_records, count(employees.id) as RECORD_COUNT
FROM accounts
left join account_settings on account_settings.account_id = accounts.id and account_settings.name = "max_allowed_records"
left join employeelists on employeelists.account_id = accounts.id
left join employees on employees.employeelist_id = employeelists.id
group by accounts.id
having coalesce(account_settings.value,0) < coalesce(RECORD_COUNT,0)
```

So what I want here is that I should get the value from account settings of the account where in the name is max_allowed_records then compare that to how many employees that account has. Unfortunately the only link between account and the employees is the employeelist. I was wondering if you guys could guide me on what I need to do here? SQLAlchemy joins? or sub queries?

Table Definitions:

```
class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = "accounts"

    id = synonym("raw_id")
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    settings = relationship("AccountSetting")

class AccountSetting(Base):
    __tablename__ = "account_settings"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    account_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("accounts.id"))
    name = Column(String(30))
    value = Column(String(1000))

class EmployeeList(Base):
    __tablename__ = "employeelists"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    raw_id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    account_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("accounts.id"))

class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = "employees"

    id = synonym("raw_id")
    raw_id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    employeelist_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("employeelists.id"), nullable=False)
```

Comment: do you have any python written? are you getting a specific error? also, if this query is working within your requirements, you can simplify this dev process by using the odbc functionality and skip the translation.

Comment: well right now I just have session.query(accountModel) since I cant really start thinking how to start into this. Like how do I join? or how do i link the subquery to the main query like what I did in the sql statement? Usual examples I get are the sub queries do not have any filters based on the main query.Also I am conditionally putting this with other filters, thats why I cannot straightly just paste in the sql code.

Comment: would you mind putting the table definitions you have on your question?

Comment: @brddawg placed them in. hope those suffice. I included only the columns necessary for this problem. I hope that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

After the whole weekend resting my mind, I was able to convert the SQL Query to SQLAlchemy Query:

```
    query = query.outerjoin(max_records_settings,\
            and_(max_records_settings.name == "max_allowed_records",\
                Account.id == max_records_settings.account_id))\
        .outerjoin(EmployeeList, Account.id == EmployeeList.account_id)\
        .add_columns(max_records_settings.value)\
        .join(Employee, EmployeeList.id == Employee.employeelist_id)\
        .group_by(Account.id)\
        .having(coalesce(func.count(Employee.id),0) > (coalesce(max_records_settings.value,0)))\
```